# Retrieve enum value using unique property

Tags: java, dictionary, enums

Is it possible to create a *generic* method or class to retrieve an enum value from a given unique property (field with getter method)?

So you would have:

```
public enum EnumToMap {
    E1("key1"),
    E2("key2"),
    ;

    private final String key;

    private EnumToMap(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

so required is the same functionality as

```
public static EnumToMap getByKey(String key)
    ...
```

would provide. Preferably without reflection and as generic as possible (but in this case it may not be possible to create a generic solution without reflection).

Clarification: So this method should work for multiple enumerations. The idea is not to have to implement the lookup over and over again.

Comment: Can't you do this using `toString` and `valueOf`?

Comment: Of course you can, but only for `"E1"` and `"E2"`.

Comment: by generic u mean that you want to use it with different enums?

Comment: @damienix Yes, that's precisely it. As said, I don't think this will be possible without reflection.

Comment: You can put key additionaly in some map in your enum while creating it this will reduce complexiti from n to 1 if you will use HashMap but you just can't avoid the "lookup" at all.

Comment: @damienix Yeah, that's the design route I usually take, but with the current processors and the fact that most enums have just 2 to, say 10 values it's just taking too much dev. time to make up for a very small amount of CPU. If the enum is very large or if you have to do millions of these lookups, then I would question the entire design...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually possible just with generics and interface.

Create and implement **interface**

```
interface WithKeyEnum {
    String getKey();
}

enum EnumToMap implements WithKeyEnum {
    ...

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public static <T extends Enum<T> & WithKeyEnum> T getByKey(Class<T> enumTypeClass, String key) {
    for (T type : enumTypeClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (type.getKey().equals(key)) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

**Usage**

```
EnumToMap instanceOfE1 = getByKey(EnumToMap.class, "key1");
```

Comment: Nice. Does require an interface for the getter, but I guess that cannot be helped without reflection.

Comment: Better use interface than use reflection ;)

Comment: The question becomes if this would be worth it. I'm not saying that there would be a better answer, but having to define an interface and method for each getter is almost as verbose. Your other answer you've provided is the route that is mostly taken, but it is not generic; it needs to be implemented again and again.

Comment: It depends how many enums you actually have. If really there are many of them, you can delegate creating of the map to some external class

Comment: So the answer for you will probably be kind of merge my 2 answers by creating object that will store and lazy load maps for all used enums (aka `Map<Enum,Map<String,Enum>>`). Additionally you might want to implement reflection version to get rid of interface however it's really not recommended. Usually you already have that getter method so it would be just adding the `implements` clause.

Comment: I'll try and generate one using reflection tomorrow, for now I'll accept this one as it is probably as close as one can get without reflection...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop generification and get O(1) complexity use `HashMap` to get it

```
public enum EnumToMap{
    E1("key1"),
    E2("key2");

    private final String key;

    private static final Map<String, EnumToMap> keys = new HashMap<String, EnumToMap>();
    static {
        for (EnumToMap value : values()) {
            keys.put(value.getKey(), value);
        }
    }

    private EnumToMap(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public static EnumToMap getByKey(String key) {
        return keys.get(key);
    }
}
```

This would be hard to just generify as there **must be an object** to store the map. Enum itself seems to be good candidate for that.